# Facebook App Event sdk 4.38.0 throws NPE in ViewHierarchy.setAppearanceOfView

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-audience-network

I'm having a problem in one of my apps where I use facebook sdk. After upgrading sdk from 4.27.0 to 4.38.0 fabric started to log this fatal exception. I don't know when or how it happens cause i can't reproduce it myself. Maybe some of you had this problem after upgrading facebook SDK.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
   at com.facebook.appevents.codeless.internal.ViewHierarchy.setAppearanceOfView(ViewHierarchy.java:182)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.getClickableElementsOfView(ButtonIndexer.java:197)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.getClickableElementsOfView(ButtonIndexer.java:206)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.getClickableElementsOfView(ButtonIndexer.java:206)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.getClickableElementsOfView(ButtonIndexer.java:206)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.getClickableElementsOfView(ButtonIndexer.java:206)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.getClickableElementsOfView(ButtonIndexer.java:206)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.getClickableElementsOfView(ButtonIndexer.java:206)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.getClickableElementsOfView(ButtonIndexer.java:206)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.getClickableElementsOfView(ButtonIndexer.java:206)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.getClickableElementsOfView(ButtonIndexer.java:206)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.getClickableElementsOfView(ButtonIndexer.java:206)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.getClickableElementsOfView(ButtonIndexer.java:206)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.getClickableElementsOfView(ButtonIndexer.java:206)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.getClickableElementsOfView(ButtonIndexer.java:206)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.getClickableElementsOfView(ButtonIndexer.java:206)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.getClickableElementsOfView(ButtonIndexer.java:206)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.getClickableElementsOfView(ButtonIndexer.java:206)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.attachListeners(ButtonIndexer.java:166)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.process(ButtonIndexer.java:161)
   at com.facebook.marketing.internal.ButtonIndexer$ViewProcessor.run(ButtonIndexer.java:145)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Comment: i see it as well on Android versions 5.1 & 4.4.4, on multiple esoteric devices like `LAVA - Grand 2`.

Comment: submitted a bug report to facebook, feel free to vote via "subscribe": https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1955482454532167

Comment: Already did. Thanks for reporting it, i haven't posted it on facebook site cause 3.38.0 is not the latest version of sdk :)

Comment: To reproduce the case you can just create ImageView and set empty BitmapDrawable: `imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        imageView.setClickable(true);` 
Then Facebook SDK in ~2% cases (currently) based on device id will enable button indexing feature and it will fail because BitmapDrawable.getBitmap can be null.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to reproduce this error in a way which you described :(

Comment: any news on this?

Comment: This issue supposed to be fixed by this commit https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/commit/a49b57673e07d41fff5fc4978bac6ef03cb44e9a.

RIght now we have to wait for next release to check it. You can find more info about this topic here https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1955482454532167.

Comment: what is the last safe version?

Comment: I'm not sure which one is the latest but 4.27.0 was working fine to me and I have downgraded sdk to this version.

Answer (score 3):

The fixed version 4.40.0 of the facebook android SDK was recently released:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4x/
- https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/releases/tag/sdk-version-4.40.0